# Making text and a PHP element display on the same line

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, footer

I'm making a footer for a site I'm developing, and it currently looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to get everything in the footer to display on a single line.  The problem is that the link to my Privacy Policy page is a PHP element that links to a WordPress menu item, and it *really* doesn't want to be on the same line with anything else. I can't get it to budge no matter what I try.

Here's the snippet from the footer.php file.  I've also tried replacing the `<span>` tag with a `<p>` tag, that hasn't worked.

```
<footer id="site_footer">
    <span>Site Name &copy; 2017 | Powered by <a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a> | <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer_nav')); ?> |</span>
</footer>
```

And here's the CSS.  I've tried adding display: inline; and display: block-inline; in every conceivable combination to these divs and it doesn't make a difference.

```
/* ~~~ Footer Navigation ~~~ */

#site_footer span {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #eeeeee;
}

#site_footer a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#site_footer ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

I've considered abandoning the PHP approach and just using `<a>` tags, but I want to keep the menu capabilities WordPress offers in case I want to add more links to the footer in the future.  Does anyone know how I can get the PHP element to sit on the same line as the rest of the text?

Comment: It would be helpful if you directly paste the link

Comment: What is the width of #site_footer in css? you should try looking into that

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, the site is currently being developed locally on my system and has yet to be hosted

Comment: Currently 950px wide with 5px padding all around.  Should be plenty side enough

Comment: Can you show DOM screenshot of footer?

Comment: First you need to check the style of the element displayed by the PHP code.  Try inspecting it in the browser and post the code here. Likely the element returned by the code is a block element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inline style `display: inline-block;` in a `div` tag

```
<footer id="site_footer">
    <span>Site Name &copy; 2017 | Powered by <a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a> |<div style="display: inline-block;"> <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer_nav')); ?> </div> |</span>
</footer>
```

Comment: I don't think this would work if the element returned by the php is a block element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

Using `display:inline-block` css style for Footer `Div` and `UL` tag.

```css
#site_footer{
display: inline-block;
}
#site_footer span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
}

#site_footer a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#site_footer ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer id="site_footer">
    <span>Site Name &copy; 2017 | Powered by <a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a> | <ul><li>Test1</li><li>Test2</li><li>Test3</li></ul> |</span>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Possible Solution is to use `javascript` to change `css` ***[display: inline-block]*** of all the element inside the class.

```
<footer id="site_footer">
    <span>Site Name &copy; 2017 | Powered by <a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a> |<div id="phpelem"> <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer_nav')); ?> </div> |</span>
</footer>

<script>
    document.getElementById("phpelem").style.display = "inline-block";
    var searchEles = document.getElementById("phpelem").children;
    for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {
        searchEles[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    }
</script>
```